# passing array from bash script to R Vector with a single argument

Tags: r, bash, list, vector, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument to an R script which I would like to be stored as a vector. What I have is this:

script.sh

```
mylist="1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2"
Rscript ./Script.R $mylist
```

Script.R

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
myVector <- args[1]
myVector[1]
myVector[5]
```

The output I'm hoping to get is

```
"1"
"2"
```

but instead I'm getting

```
[1] "1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2"
[1] NA
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `mylist` is a single string, not a vector of strings/numbers. Try:

```
myVector <- unlist(strsplit(args[1],","))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just to provide an alternative approach, you can use a shell array variable to store your vector at the shell level, and then pass it to the R script as one element per argument:

**script.sh**

```
mylist=(1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2);
Rscript ./Script.R "${mylist[@]}";
```

**Script.R**

```
myVector <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=T);
myVector[1];
myVector[5];
```

Demo:

```
./script.sh;
## [1] "1"
## [1] "2"
```